# Resize support in Google Chrome ARC app

Tags: google-chrome-arc

Is there any metadata setting which will enable resize support in ARC app? I tried setting "resize" : "scale" in metadata, but it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29424464/4744301), you can try `{"resize" : "reconfigure"}` in Chrome 42+.  Note that if you publish a ZIP generated from Chrome 42 it will be limited to Chrome 42+ users.

This metadata is ignored for Chrome 41, so once you know it works for your App (please test, this is not guaranteed), you can publish for Chrome 41 with the additional metadata, and users of Chrome 42+ will automatically get the new functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `{"resize": "reconfigure"}` previously.